# Cannot create data frame with 0 rows in R

Tags: r

I have R running on two computers. Both are running the same version as well as OS (windows) when I type `version`. Here is the output from both computers:

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.1                         
year           2018                        
month          07                          
day            02                          
svn rev        74947                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
nickname       Feather Spray
```

But on one of the computers the following command fails:

```
tmp <- data.frame(start, end)
```

Error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :
  cannot coerce class '"function"' to a data frame
```

Why does this happen and how can I resolve this error? I'm basically trying to create a dataframe with no rows (0 rows) and column names called `start` and `end`. It works on one computer though!

Comment: I believe the error is intended. Could you just change your code to `data.frame(start = c(), end = c())`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is because `start` is a function in the `stats` package. The `data.frame` function expects the arguments to be a vector of some type.

Phil's comment will work, but if you want to produce an empty data.frame object with specified names, you will likely want to also know the classes of each column and just pass an empty vector into it.

```
tmp <- data.frame(start = character(), end = character())
```

of course there are many vector constructor functions in R you can choose from - `integer()`, `numeric()`, `factor()`, `list()`, etc. This is generally the hardest part of the problem - knowing which class you want the empty columns to be.

Comment: thank you! thankfully i know the datatype in the frame in advance, phew!